# Accessing Email id From Principal where Authentication done in Azure Active directory

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, azure-active-directory

I have written a custom application where it has SSO with the Azure Active Directory. Once the user was Authenticated successfully all the API services need to send the JWT token to access of the Services. I am trying to find the email id in the Authentication using below

```
@GetMapping("/details")    
public Authentication getUserDetails()
{
//logger.info();

    Authentication auth=SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    return auth;
 }
```

When i call the Api i can see the below response as a Json Response

```
{
"authorities": [
    {
        "authority": "ROLE_Admin"
    }
],
"details": null,
"authenticated": true,
"principal": {
    "userGroups": [
        {
            "objectID": "a5f70709",
            "displayName": "Outlook"
        }
    ],
    "name": "Karthik",
    "subject": "J",
    "claim": "65f9",
    "issuer": "",
    "claims": {
    },
    "uniqueName": "karthik@microsoftoutlook.com",
    "upn": "karthik@microsoftoutlook.com",
    "kid": ""
},
"credentials": null,
"name": "com.microsoft.azure.spring.autoconfigure"
}
```

Since my email id is in principal object i'm trying to cast to a Custom class & casting to a hashmap where i will get using key. But both ways im getting casting error.

*Casting through Hashmap*

```
    CustomPrincipal principal=(CustomPrincipal)auth.getPrincipal();
```

*Casting through Hashmap*

```
Map<Object, Object> details = (HashMap<Object,Object>) auth.getPrincipal();
```

All i need is emailid from the Authentication Object.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question depends on how you have Spring Security configured. Start by calling `System.out.println(auth.getPrincipal().getClass().getName())` to see what class you have as the authenticated principal or use your IDE to set a breakpoint and inspect the value.

Most likely, this class will contain the user's OpenId Connect token (a JSON Web Token) that you will then have to decode.